# Apache LimitExcept only to GET and POST methods

Tags: apache, security, post, get, httpd.conf

I have the current configuration in my httpd.conf file.I am trying to remove the vulnerability Authentication Bypass Using HTTP Verb Tampering. I only want to allow certain HTTP request headers, Get and Post in the below example and a different header should throw an error.

```
DocumentRoot "c:/dev"
<Directory "C:/dev">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews Includes
    AllowOverride Limit
    <LimitExcept GET POST>
      Order deny,allow
     Deny from all
    </LimitExcept>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

This configuration is still allowing other http request headers like put, options etc. I am using postman api to test my changes. Please help!

Answer (score 4):

This is how you can limit to GET/POST/OPTIONS. Note: NIST Stigs V-26396 states that this should not be applied to the root  but only the others such as in my example  (/etc/apache2/apache2.conf):

[image]

It appears that this would work as well :

```
<Location /var/www/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        <LimitExcept POST GET>
           Deny from all
        </LimitExcept>
</Location>

<Location /usr/share/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        <LimitExcept POST GET>
           Deny from all
        </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

Further reading :

- https://vaulted.io/library/disa-stigs-srgs/apache_22_server_for_unix_security_technical_implementation_guide/V-26396
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#limitexcept

Answer (score 1):

Try this settings

```
<Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        <LimitExcept POST GET>
           Deny from all
        </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

Comment: Please add explanation of your solution

Comment: should not put this in the root folder

Comment: @MikeQ: why not?

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk  I think it was security reasons.  Read this (see the bottom right of this page) let me know if I am reading corectly:  https://vaulted.io/library/disa-stigs-srgs/apache_22_server_for_unix_security_technical_implementation_guide/V-26396

Comment: @MikeQ: That link does say you shouldn't put it in the root folder, but as far as I can tell it doesn't really say why. I certainly don't have any reason to allow anything other than GET POST OPTIONS and HEAD in the document root either.

Answer (score -1):

The LimitExcept directive is the inverse of Limit directive. It allows applying a set of access restrictions to all listed http methods except for the ones listed with the LimitExcept directive. See this link: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#limitexcept. So the access restrictions are applied to all http methods except for the ones listed with LimitExcept.

In your case the problem seems to be with the access control directives. See this link for more information: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_access_compat.html#order

You can try to remove the directives below